# How to get last 7 days record from table as per date using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need one help. I need to etch last 7 days record including today as per date using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

> db_special:

```
id             date                                        name

1       11/27/2017 11:14:48 AM                              Raj

2       10/26/2017 12:11:30 PM                              Rahul
```

Here I need to fetch the data as per `date` field value. `Date` field format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and my requirement is to fetch all data from the table from last 7 days including `today` also using PHP and MySQL. Please help.

Comment: What do you understand by 7 days? 7×24 hours or strictly the date minus 7? Knowing that helps you deal with summer/wintertime and leap seconds..

Comment: it should be 7*24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing your MySQL as text in the non ISO format `mm/dd/yyyy`.  So you will need to do a conversion to date in order to be able to access any of the date functionality which MySQL offers.  The `STR_TO_DATE` function comes in handy here.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    id, date, name
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(col, '%m/%d/%Y') > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
    STR_TO_DATE(col, '%m/%d/%Y') <= CURDATE();
```

The second inequality can be omitted if you do not expect to have any future records.

Note that moving forward if you plan to do date things with your `date` column, then you should consider making this column a bona-fide date type, rather than text.

Note: It appears that you actually have a time component in your date string as well.  As [this demo shows](http://rextester.com/PXVRT50206), if we use the format mask `%m/%d/%Y` on such a timestamp, it will strip the time component entirely, leaving only the date behind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
select * from db_special
where date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

---

You can use `current_date` as your specified (any) formate

```
SELECT * FROM db_special WHERE WEEK (date) = WEEK( current_date ) - 1 AND YEAR( date) = YEAR( current_date );
```

Comment: This won't work, because the OP stored the dates as text in a non ISO format, q.v. the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL query for this would be like this, if your "date" column is a string:

```
select *
from db_special
where STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') >=date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
  and STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') < date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

if stored as proper dates then you don't need str_to_date()

```
select *
from db_special
where date >=date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
  and date < date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Note curdate() returns today's date at 00:00:00 (the start of the day) so to include all data for today you must add 1 day to the current date.

Comment: I run your query and no data are coming even I have one record with date `11/27/2017 11:14:48 AM`.

Comment: is your `date` column really a stored as a date or datetime, or is it a string (char/varchar)?

Comment: You really should not store dates as strings, it's a very bad idea. Not only will it slow our queries a lot but you can get conversion errors as well.